# npm gyp build error on windows 8

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, gyp

My npm installation appears to be incomplete in some way :/.   I've been testing with npm -g install buffertools --msvs_version=2013 , but I have tried quite a few others.  I thought my setup worked previously under node .10 but after upgrading to 0.12.5, it's been non-stop headaches.  I removed everything and reinstalled, no love.  My Windows 7 box had no trouble :/.

My setup:
Python 2.7.10
node 0.12.5
npm 2.11.2
VStudio 2013 (Professional)

The error:

```
...\.node-gyp\0.12.5\Release\node.lib : fatal error LNK1106: invalid file or disk full: cannot seek to 0x1B844 [...\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\buffertools\build\buffertools.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe` fail
ed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_mo
dules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
```

I tried updating/reinstalling node-gyp
I tried updating npm
I tried using --msvs_version=2013
I've tried installing the node-v0.12.5-x86 and the node-v0.12.5-x64 versions... :).  I'm attempting to run this on a Surface 2 Pro with Windows 8.1 on it.
I also installed with Windows 7.1 SDK.

I only have one version of Python installed, and it is in path.  Also, I am running npm in a command shell as Administrator.

I'm not that familiar with the internals of what npm/node-gyp is doing, so I'm not sure where to go next in debugging this problem without diving into the internals of npm (which I'd rather not do :( ).  I gather it is attempting to kick off a Vis Studio build on a vcxproj.  Therein, I'm sure this is just a stupid configuration piece/thing I've forgotten to install.  I'm especially weirded out because I had no problems with node 0.10 which I had installed and working no problem on this machine up until today.

Answer (score 0):

I could be totally off here, but just a thought - you'll likely need Administrative privileges to save to the Program Files directory. The error seems to indicate that it's unable to wri

Are you running this with a privileged account?

Comment: Yeah, I should have specified I'm running in a command shell as Administrator.  I've added that to the OP.

Comment: I haven't looked at the npm piping in detail, it could be that somewhere it forks processes/threads with different permissions from the initiating shell.  I also have seen nebulous references to an incompatibility in node with Windows 8, but without knowing the nature of the "bug".  I did some searches, but I have not yet found an explanation.